# odbc cause high mysql server load

Tags: mysql, excel, odbc

I have heard that excel-based ODBC connections can cause high server load (repeatedly warned at least).

Is this a catch-all disclaimer, or is there a serious issue here? 
I plan to have 5-8 excel sheets that would be open all day updating one table (with about 65 cells) every minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't imagine it would cause much load.... but surely the best way to find out is to try it in a test environment and monitor the server metrics...